# 'Navbar' is defined but never used. eslint(no-unused-vars)

Tags: reactjs

First time using react, I am trying to import components but they won't show up

```js
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
  <h1>working?</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```js
import React from 'react'
import {BiSearch} from 'react-icons/bi'
import {BsPerson} from 'react-icons/bs'

function Navbar() {
  return (
    <div className='navbar'>
        <div className='logo'>
            <h2>BEACHES. </h2>
        </div>
        <ul className='nav-menu'>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Destinations</li>
            <li>Travel</li>
            <li>Book</li>
            <li>Views</li>
        </ul>
      <div className='nav-icons'>
        <BiSearch className='icon'/>
        <BsPerson className='icon'/>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

First, install the following module `npm install --save-dev eslint-plugin-react`.

Then, in your `.eslintrc.json`, under extends, include the following plugin:

```json
'extends': [
    'plugin:react/recommended'
]
```

Comment: You've imported it correctly, as best i can tell. The lint error is pointing out that you haven't actually used it. Render a `<Navbar />` somewhere in App.

Comment: Hi Steph, as how Nicholas mentioned. The linter are just pointing you that your declaring a variable without using it. Remove the import line or comment it or implement the <Navbar> component in <App> component. This should work